# Testing react-router with Shallow rendering

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I have my react-router component such as :

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    path="/abc"
    render={() => <ComponentTemplateABC component={containerABC} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/def"
    render={() => <ComponentTemplateDEF component={containerDEF} />}
  />
  ...
  ...
</Switch>
```

I wish to test the routing to ensure the respective component is rendered for each route. However, I do not wish to use mount for testing the routing, only wish to use shallow rendering.

Below is what my test looks like currently:

```
  test('abc path should route to containerABC component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/abc']}>
          <Switch>
            <AppRouter />
          </Switch>
        </MemoryRouter>
      </Provider>,
    );
    jestExpect(wrapper.find(containerABC)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```

This test does not work with shallow, because shallow won't render the full child hierarchy. So I tried an alternate approach:

```
test('abc path should render correct routes and route to containerABC component', () => {
 const wrapper = shallow(<AppRouter />);

 const pathMap = wrapper.find(Route).reduce((pathMap, route) => {
 const routeProps = route.props();
 pathMap[routeProps.path] = routeProps.component;
 return pathMap;
 }, {});

 jestExpect(pathMap['/abc']).toBe(containerABC);
});
```

This test does not work for me, because I am using render in my routing code instead of Component directly as in below:

```
<Route path="..." **render**={() => <Component.. component={container..} />}
```

Hence, I am unable to test my routes. How do I test my routes using shallow rendering or as above or basically, any other approach that does not use mount?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this with react-router@4 or @5? I'm having issues with @5, but I think there are solutions for @4.

Answer (score 0):

So far I may suggest you different ways to test that:

1. Mocking `ComponentABC` + `mount()`

```
import containerABC from '../../containerABC.js';

jest.mock('../../containerABC.js', () => <span id="containerABC" />);
...
  const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/abc']}>
        <Switch>
          <AppRouter />
        </Switch>
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>,
  );
  jestExpect(wrapper.find(containerABC)).toHaveLength(1);
```

2. `shallow()` + `dive()` + `renderProp()`:

```
   const wrapper = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/abc']}>
          <Switch>
            <AppRouter />
          </Switch>
        </MemoryRouter>
      </Provider>,
    );
    jestExpect(wrapper.find(AppRouter)
      .dive()
      .find(Route)
      .filter({path: '/abc'})
      .renderProp('render', { history: mockedHistory})
      .find(ContainerABC)
    ).toHaveLength(1);
```

Comment: using jest mocks is lousy.   Don't use mocking framework magic just to get stuff to work